# Can I combine the results a single line?

Tags: postgresql, case

My query is:

```
select urunbolgesi,sube,
count(case etiket when 'BOŞTA' then 1 else null end) as bosta,
count(case etiket when 'ZİMMET' then 1 else null end) as zimmet,
count(case etiket when 'ISKART' then 1 else null end) as iskart
from tblurun 
where urunadi='CASPER-11'
group by urunbolgesi,sube,etiket,urunadi
```

My result is:

```
urunbolgesi sube    bosta   zimmet  iskart
A           qwer    0       1       0       
B           asdf    5       0       0       
B           asdf    0       0       1      
B           asdf    0       1       0
```

What I want that is:

```
urunbolgesi sube    bosta   zimmet  iskart
A           qwer    0       1       0       
B           asdf    5       1       1
```

Can I combine with code above result?

Comment: Not easy to say without example data but i think you only need to use `group by urunbolgesi, sube` instead off `group by urunbolgesi, sube, etiket, urunadi`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I change little but your comment is right. Problem is in the group by.